# Multiple htaccess redirections with regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to create redirects:

www.mysite.com/out/cars/ to https://cars.example.com/?aid=123 (not working)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/cars [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://cars.othersite.com/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/cars/volvo/ to https://cars.example.com/volvo/?aid=123 (works)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/cars/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://cars.othersite.com/%1/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/cars/volvo/vagon/ to https://cars.example.com/volvo/vagon/?aid=123 (works)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://cars.othersite.com/%1/%2/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/bikes/ to https://bikes.example.com/?aid=123 (not working)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/bikes [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bikes.othersite.com/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/bikes/suzuki/ to https://bikes.example.com/suzuki/?aid=123 (not working)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/bikes/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bikes.othersite.com/%1/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/bikes/suzuki/volusia to https://bikes.example.com/suzuki/volusia/?aid=123 (works)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/bikes/([^/]+)/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://bikes.othersite.com/%1/%2/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

www.mysite.com/out/atv/bmw/black/big/best/ to https://atv.example.com/bmw/black/big/best/?aid=123 (works)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/atv/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://atv.example.com/%1/%2/%3/?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

Thing is, some rules work but not all of them. I guess they interfere in some way, but I tried to change what I could and nothing worked for 100% :(

What happens is for example that this:

```
www.mysite.com/out/bikes/suzuki/
```

redirects to:

```
https://bikes.example.com/suzuki/%20http/?aid=123
```

etc. :(

Anybody could help? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe a simpler regex would still suffice?  (inferring the apparent rules from the examples, since they are not explicitly stated)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*?/out/(cars|bikes|atv)/?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://$1.example.com/$2?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

https://regex101.com/r/vp9jrA/2

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatelly it just redirects me to http://.example.com/?aid=123 . It's like it is not using capturing groups :( Dont know why...

Comment: when I change $1 and $2 to %1 and %2 it works better, but not completely. `www.mysite.com/out/bikes/suzuki/volusia/` redirects to `bikes.example.com/suzuki/?aid=123`. It misses part of second capturing group. Dont you know why?

Comment: I undid that edit (wasn't sure how string begins, honestly). however I do not know why/how the pattern would fail to matcht the rest of the string in the second issue (works on regex101)

Comment: I dont understand it too :( Not sure if server settings can be the problem?

Comment: I had to change your code to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /out/([^/]+)/?(.*) [NC]` and 
`RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com/%2?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]` . Difference is in **%{REQUEST_URI}** and **%1** and **%2** ($1 is for use in RewriteRule). Now it works like a charm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^out/cars/?$ https://cars.othersite.com/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/cars/([^/]+)/?$ https://cars.othersite.com/$1/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ https://cars.othersite.com/$1/$2/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/bikes/?$ https://bikes.othersite.com/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/bikes/([^/]+)/?$ https://bikes.othersite.com/$1/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/bikes/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ https://bikes.othersite.com/$1/$2/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^out/atv/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://atv.example.com/$1/$2/$3/?aid=123 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: I dont know why but these one line redirects dont work :(

Comment: Did you add other lines?